# Android infalter add view to layout

Tags: android, android-view, layout-inflater

Im trying to add a view which consist of a background and a moving cloud to a layout that has buttons and checkboxes. I tried getLayoutInflater to merge both of them togather but it forced close. here is MainActivity code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{

MyCloud myView;
float x, y;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    myView = new MyCloud(this);
    getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.RGBA_8888);
    setContentView(myView);


    View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null, false);

    this.addContentView(view, null);
}
}
```

Here is the View activity:

```
public class MyCloud extends View{

Bitmap cloud;
int ChangingX;
int ChangingY;
int x, y;

BitmapFactory.Options options;
Bitmap preparedBitmap;

public MyCloud(Context context) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    super(context);

    setFocusable(true);

    options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
    options.inDither = true;
    options.inScaled = false;
    options.inDither = false;
    options.inPurgeable = true;
    preparedBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
            R.drawable.bg, options);
    Log.d("bitmap", String.valueOf(preparedBitmap));

    cloud = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.cloud);

    ChangingX = 50;
    ChangingY = 50;
    x = 0;
    y = 0;
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.drawBitmap(preparedBitmap, 0, 0, null); // for background
    canvas.drawBitmap(cloud, ChangingX , 50, null); // for cloud 
    if (ChangingX < canvas.getWidth())
        ChangingX += 2;
    else
        ChangingX = 50;

    invalidate();

}

}
```

The layout Code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/bg"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="170dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="58dp"
    android:text="Button" />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="27dp"
    android:text="CheckBox" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

The error I have:

```
06-15 12:34:20.801: E/AndroidRuntime(528): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-15 12:34:20.801: E/AndroidRuntime(528): 
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
ComponentInfo{com.cloud/com.cloud.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-15 12:34:20.801: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
06-15 12:34:20.801: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
06-15 12:34:20.801: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
06-15 12:34:20.801: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
06-15 12:34:20.801: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-15 12:34:20.801: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
06-15 12:34:20.801: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
06-15 12:34:20.801: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-15 12:34:20.801: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
06-15 12:34:20.801: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
06-15 12:34:20.801: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
06-15 12:34:20.801: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-15 12:34:20.801: E/AndroidRuntime(528): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-15 12:34:20.801: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  
at android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams.<init>(ViewGroup.java:3573)
06-15 12:34:20.801: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  
at android.view.ViewGroup$MarginLayoutParams.<init>(ViewGroup.java:3723)
06-15 12:34:20.801: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  
at android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams.<init>(FrameLayout.java:487)
06-15 12:34:20.801: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  
at    android.widget.FrameLayout.generateLayoutParams(FrameLayout.java:431)
06-15 12:34:20.801: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  
at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:1975)
06-15 12:34:20.801: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  
at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:1865)
06-15 12:34:20.801: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  
at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:1845)
06-15 12:34:20.801: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.addContentView(PhoneWindow.java:229)
06-15 12:34:20.801: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  
at android.app.Activity.addContentView(Activity.java:1681)
06-15 12:34:20.801: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  
at com.cloud.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:35)
06-15 12:34:20.801: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
06-15 12:34:20.801: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
06-15 12:34:20.801: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  ... 11 more
```

Now I have never used getLayoutInflater before so can you please be patient with me and show me in Code how I can fix this problem or if there is any alternative way to add the view to the layout. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a LinearLayout or Relayout in your activity_main.xml

Inflate activity_main.xml

```
myView = new MyCloud(this); 
View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null, false);
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.ll);
ll.addView(myView); // add custom view to linealayout
setContentView(view); // set the inflated layout to activity
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="170dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="58dp"
    android:text="Button" />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="27dp"
    android:text="CheckBox" />
 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/ll"
        android:layout_above="@+id/checkBox1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
      />
 </RelativeLayout>
```

snap shot

[image]

Edit:

Alternative

You can just have

```
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  myView = new MyCloud(this);  
  LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.ll);
  ll.addView(myView); // add custom view to linealayout
```

And in your `RelativeLayout`

```
   android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
```

Comment: you need to have button and check box in the layout as well

Comment: there are in the xml. Can you check the xml code above? Im using relative layout and used your code but instead of linear i used i relative and i added an ID to it in the XML

Comment: check the edit. place your linearlayout wherever you like and then set the content of the custom view to the linearlayout

Comment: Wow thanks for your efforts it worked but it seems the view was only added in the linear layout so i have the view background in the linearlayout while in main activity there is no background.

Comment: set the background to your inflated view.